# Javascript: How to generate a drop-down list with loops and how do I use change events to display info from an array

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dropdown, onchange

so essentially I was given an array of countries and I must first generate a loop into a drop-down list that displays the country names.

Second, the value attributes for each item in the list should be the country code

Then I must add an event handler for the drop-down lists change event so that when a country is selected it will display the capital of the city.

I've tried playing around with loops and change event handlers but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help is appreciated thank you.

I know it's a mess but I'm having a tough time.

```js
var countries = [{
    code: "AR",
    name: "Argentina",
    capital: "Buenos Aires"
  },
  {
    code: "AT",
    name: "Austria",
    capital: "Vienna"
  },
  {
    code: "BE",
    name: "Belgium",
    capital: "Brussels"
  },
  {
    code: "CA",
    name: "Canada",
    capital: "Ottawa"
  }
];

var select = document.getElementById('selectCountries');

for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
  var optco = countries[i];
  var opt = document.createElement('options');
  opt.textContent = optco;
  opt.value = optco;
  select.appendChild(opt);

  // loop for grabbing each country name and displaying it in the drop-down
}


document.getElementById('countries').innerHTML

// use an onchange event
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Array Countries</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: powderblue">
  <h1> Country Info Guide </h1>
  <p> Please Select a Country for More Information</p>
  <form method=get action=whatever.php>
    Select a country:
    <select id="selectCountries" onchange="GetCapital(this)">
    </select>
    <div>
      <p>
      </p>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

this way:

1 - Select elements have native methods for adding options (no needs of  `select.appendChild(opt)` )
use [HTMLSelect​Element​.add(item[, before])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add)

2 - Options element have a constuctor (no needs of `document.createElement('option')`)
use [new Option(text, value, defaultSelected, selected)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option)
to directly set options attributes in one instruction

```js
const countries = 
  [ { code: 'AR', name: 'Argentina', capital: 'Buenos Aires' } 
  , { code: 'AT', name: 'Austria',   capital: 'Vienna'       } 
  , { code: 'BE', name: 'Belgium',   capital: 'Brussels'     } 
  , { code: 'CA', name: 'Canada',    capital: 'Ottawa'       } 
  ] 

const myForm = document.forms['my-form']

countries.forEach(c => myForm.selectCountries.add( new Option(c.name,c.code )))

myForm.selectCountries.oninput = e =>
  {
  let cod = myForm.selectCountries.value
  console.clear()
  console.log( cod , '=>', JSON.stringify( countries.find(x=>x.code===cod)))
  }
```

```css
body  {
  background-color: powderblue;
  }
```

```html
  <h1> Country Info Guide </h1>

  <p> Please Select a Country for More Information</p>
  
  <form method=get action=whatever.php  id="my-form">
    Select a country:

    <select name="selectCountries"></select>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You where close.

- `.createElement('options')` is `option` not `options`
- `countries[i]` in loop is whole one object from array with all data for one country. SO you need to append just parts of it  with `.name` and `.code`:

  ```
  opt.textContent = optco.name;
  opt.value = optco.code;
  ```
- Use this as function on change for example:

...

```
function GetCapital(event) {
  let res = countries.filter(e => e.code == event.value).map(e=>e.capital).toString()
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = res
}
```

`event` is `select` element, `event.value` is selected value (witch you appended before) on change.

Then you filter your initial array of countries to extract the one with code you selected from drop down.

```js
var countries = [{
    code: "AR",
    name: "Argentina",
    capital: "Buenos Aires"
  },
  {
    code: "AT",
    name: "Austria",
    capital: "Vienna"
  },
  {
    code: "BE",
    name: "Belgium",
    capital: "Brussels"
  },
  {
    code: "CA",
    name: "Canada",
    capital: "Ottawa"
  }
];

var select = document.getElementById('selectCountries');

for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
  var optco = countries[i];
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.textContent = optco.name;
  opt.value = optco.code;
  select.appendChild(opt);

  // loop for grabbing each country name and displaying it in the drop-down
}

function GetCapital(event) {
  let res = countries.filter(e => e.code == event.value).map(e=>e.capital).toString()
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = res
}


// use an onchange event
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Array Countries</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: powderblue">
  <h1> Country Info Guide </h1>
  <p> Please Select a Country for More Information</p>
  <form method=get action=whatever.php>
    Select a country:
    <select id="selectCountries" onchange="GetCapital(this)">
    </select>
    <div id="result">
      <p>
      </p>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @MisterJojo Thats cool and all but I fixed OP's attempt. But to be also honest, I always forgot about option constructor anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Array Countries</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: powderblue">
    <h1> Country Info Guide </h1>   
    <p> Please Select a Country for More Information</p>
    <form method="get" action="whatever.php">
        Select a country:
        <!-- here we use onfocus event -->
        <select name="countries" id="selectCountries" onfocus="getCountries()"></select>
    </form>
    <script>
        // const for JSON array
        const countries = [{ code: "AR", name: "Argentina", capital: "Buenos Aires" },
        { code: "AT", name: "Austria", capital: "Vienna" },
        { code: "BE", name: "Belgium", capital: "Brussels" },
        { code: "CA", name: "Canada", capital: "Ottawa" }];

        // use let instead of var
        let select = document.getElementById('selectCountries');

        function getCountries() {
            // loop to append data only if select is empty
            if(!select.innerHTML){
                // loop for grabbing each country name and displaying it in the drop-down
                for (let i=0; i < countries.length; i++){
                    // read more on how to use object destructuring
                    let { name } = countries[i];
                    // <option value="value">innerHTML</option>
                    let option = document.createElement('OPTION');
                    option.value = name;
                    option.innerHTML = name;
                    // append current option to select
                    select.appendChild(option);  
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is an array of objects, so you can iterate over the objects using a for in loop. Then an eventListener for the change, use the event.target to get the value and match it with the `array[key].capital` and display it to the div on the page with `display.textConent`.

***NOTE:*** We use a ***disabled*** ***option*** and select it by default as  we are using ***change*** for the event listener, this way it changes if the user selects the first option, **Argentina**

```js
const countries = [{
    code: "AR",
    name: "Argentina",
    capital: "Buenos Aires"
  },
  {
    code: "AT",
    name: "Austria",
    capital: "Vienna"
  },
  {
    code: "BE",
    name: "Belgium",
    capital: "Brussels"
  },
  {
    code: "CA",
    name: "Canada",
    capital: "Ottawa"
  }
];
const selectCountries = document.getElementById('selectCountries')
const display = document.getElementById('display')

function createSel(arr) {
  let code, name, capital = ''
  for (let key in arr) {
    let opt = document.createElement('option')
    code = arr[key].code
    name = arr[key].name
    capital = arr[key].capital
    opt.value = code
    opt.textContent = name
    selectCountries.append(opt)
  }
}

createSel(countries)

function findCapital(e){
  for (let key in countries) {
    if (countries[key].code === e.target.value) {
      display.textContent = `${countries[key].name}'s capital is ${countries[key].capital}`
    }
  }
}

selectCountries.addEventListener('change', findCapital)
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Array Countries</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: powderblue">

  <h1> Country Info Guide </h1>

  <p> Please Select a Country for More Information</p>


  <select id="selectCountries">
    <option selected disabled>Select a country Below:</option>
  </select>
  <div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: 6 one, half a dozen the other